# Run both Javascript-function and PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on a contact-footer. The HTML looks like this:

```
<form action="indexTest.php" method="post">
                    <input spellcheck="false" class="first" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"> 
                    <input spellcheck="false" class="first" type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"> 
                    <textarea rows="5" spellcheck="false" class="last" type="text" name="message" placeholder="message"></textarea> 
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" id="button" onclick="banner()">    
                </form>
```

Now if I click on "submit", the PHP-file is running. But as you see in the code, you see "onclick="banner()". But this doesn't work. Only the PHP works. It would like to run both a Javascript-function and PHP.

I want to achieve that if you click on 'submit'; the PHP-file runs and a banner is displayed by Javascript.

Comment: [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: When you submit the form it'll redirect you to `indexTest.php` and your banner will disappear. How do you expect it to do both?

Comment: [Example of a form with Ajax](http://codegarycode.com/post.php?title=Submitting+an+HTML+form+via+Ajax)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `onsubmit()` function which first execute function then action event will work

```
<form onsubmit="return banner();" action="indexTest.php" method="post"  name="theForm">
                        <input spellcheck="false" class="first" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"> 
                        <input spellcheck="false" class="first" type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"> 
                        <textarea rows="5" spellcheck="false" class="last" type="text" name="message" placeholder="message"></textarea> 
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" id="button">    
                    </form> 

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function banner(){
                            alert('working');
                            document.theForm.submit();
                        }
                    </script>
```

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

The javascript function can be attached to the form onsubmit event.

```
<form action="indexTest.php" method="post" onsubmit="banner()">
                <input spellcheck="false" class="first" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"> 
                <input spellcheck="false" class="first" type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"> 
                <textarea rows="5" spellcheck="false" class="last" type="text" name="message" placeholder="message"></textarea> 
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" id="button">
</form>
```

The onclick event maybe just run when the button type is "button".